# Is possible to change color of ScrollBar?

Tags: android, android-widget

I changed in ScrollView

```
android:fadeScrollbars="false"
```

to ScrollBar be visible and it works fine. My question is possible to change color of ScrollBar ? ( Default is gray and my background is gray so there is small contrast between ).

Comment: Scrollbar color varies between vendors though

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can with `android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/youdrawable`

In my case, for instance yourdrawable is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <gradient android:startColor="#66C0C0C0" android:endColor="#66C0C0C0"
        android:angle="45"/>

    <corners android:radius="6dp" />

</shape>
```

Comment: how about the color of the fastScrollBar?

Answer (score 6):

You can use:`android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/yourImage"`
, where 'yourImage' can be a small 2 pixel image of ur desired color